# Javascript cronjob

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, cron, google-visualization

How to have a scheduler weekly sending via email of report with the attachment of chart(made by javascript) without any user interaction to the browser?
A cronjob like javascript.

Is there any other option other than using server side javascript like node.js?

Comment: Other than node.js, it's all client side. Meaning, you need a client to visit the site to run it.

Comment: You need server side language to do this.

Comment: If you have a webpage that, in cooperation with your backend, generates the attachments and mails them out, you can trigger visiting the site with a powershell or batch script and have that script trigger with the standard windows sheduler, so you can do alot of the calculations in javascript. You will however need a backend to do the emailing for you and to grab the data you need to create the attachment. In the end, doing everything in the backend is probably way better though.

Comment: @ evolutionxbox - I want to avoid that because if no one visit the page function will not also run.

any alternative from node.js?

Comment: I hadn't heard of any, but @Quentin has shown otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three basic options:

- Use a JavaScript engine that is not built into a browser. Node.js is the standard for that these days, but other options like Rhino do exist. This assumes that the charting code doesn't depend on any browser APIs.
- Use a browser, but drive it programatically (e.g. via Selenium or PhantomJS)
- Rewrite the report generator so it doesn't use JavaScript

Comment: The best option I see is to use the node.js, But I was worried because the node.js team is releasing new versions at a rapid pace, and so I should expect a little work every 3-6 months to update to the latest version.

Comment: You don't *have* to run the latest version. Unless you need something in the bleeding edge, use a packaged version (assuming you are running on something like Debian which has a sane package management system) and just use the version it supplies. You'll only have to worry about updating things if there is an update from the package system (which will usually only be a security patch with no side effects if you use Debian Stable).